# python lxml xtree not getting number from span

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

Im trying to learn how to use different languages for different things, and im in the middle of learning web scraping using lxml, at the moment I am just trying to get a supposed page number from a span header in html but i keep getting back 0 or different other stuff with each command i try through the pages variable.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
    
url = 'https://mangadex.org'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    
mangaLinks = tree.xpath('//a[@class="manga_title text-truncate "]//@href')
    
manga = requests.get(url+mangaLinks[0])
tree2 = html.fromstring(manga.content)
    
mangaChaptersLink = tree2.xpath('//a[@class="text-truncate"]/@href')
    
chapter = requests.get(url+mangaChaptersLink[0])
tree3 = html.fromstring(chapter.content)
    
pages = tree3.xpath('//span[@class="total-pages"]/text()')
    
print(pages)
```

i keep getting a return value of 0 i would really appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with your code but rather with the way the particular webpage is built. They must be using javascript to populate this value at some point. this is evidenced by using curl to get the page:

```
curl https://mangadex.org/chapter/934446/1
```

I see: `<span class="total-pages">0</span>` from this.

This means you will have to do something more involved where you make the same request that the javascript is making to get the total number of pages.

Looks like what you want is in: https://mangadex.org/scripts/reader.min.js, but sadly this seems to be accessing a back-end model. This means to scrape the same page you may want to look into an automated-browser or something instead (which runs javascript). Selenium is a popular option for this.